# Taylor Polynomal and Conic Section

Tags: taylor-expansion, conic-sections

A real function of two variable is given by:
$f(x,y) =\exp(x+y) \cdot \cos(x-y)$.

**The approximating polynomal of $\boldsymbol{2}$nd degree for $\boldsymbol{f(x,y)}$ with converging point $\boldsymbol{(x_0,y_0) =(0,0)}$ called $\boldsymbol{P_2(x,y)}$.**

a) Find $P_2(x,y)$ 
b) Equation $P_2(x,y)=0$ describes a conic section in the $(x,y)$ plane. Give a characteristic of the conic section.

Any help would be great on how to approach this question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you know that a Taylor series about $(0,0)$ takes the form

$$f(x,y) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{mn} x^m y^n $$

$$a_{mn} = \frac1{m! n!}\left [\frac{\partial^{m+n} f}{\partial x^m \partial y^n} \right ]_{x=0,y=0} $$

You want the following $6$ terms: $a_{00}$, $a_{10}$,$a_{01}$,$a_{20}$,$a_{11}$,$a_{02}$.

To figure out which conic section you have, look at the sign of $a_{11}^2-4 a_{20} a_{02}$.

Comment: Your computations will give you $2xy+x+y+1=0 \Leftrightarrow y=-\dfrac{x+1}{2x+1}$ which is an hyperbola. The consequence is that you have a saddle point at the origin.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Cool, but I left my answer as is so that the OP could work out the result for himself.

Comment: I understand your point. I think that giving the answer leaves some work to do... Regarding the nature of the conic section, I have found with my students, that they had not the idea to find rather easily the nature of a conic section using the "trick" of expressing one variable as a function (or as 2 functions) of the other variable. The knowledge about conic sections is now very scarce and criteria like the sign of $ a_{11}^2-4 a_{20} a_{02}$       
is no longer part of the curricula, in most countries, alas...